# Analytical integral running slow

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, numerical-integration

I am calculating an integral with Mathematica, but it is running super slow!

Do you think there is a way to speed up the computation of A3? Maybe I should define my functions in a different way, but I am not sure how. Here is the code I am using:

```
RA = {0, 0, 0}; RB = {d, 0, 0}; Inf = Infinity;

g1[x_, y_, z_] = (2 a1/Pi)^(3/4) Exp[-a1 ({x, y, z} - RA).({x, y, z} - RA)];
g2[x_, y_, z_] = (2 a1/Pi)^(3/4) Exp[-a1 ({x, y, z} - RB).({x, y, z} - RB)];

g1g2 = Chop[Integrate[g1[x, y, z]*g2[x, y, z], {x, -Inf, Inf}, {y, -Inf, Inf}, 
       {z, -Inf, Inf}] /. {a1 -> 0.416613, d -> 1.401}, 10^-7]

chi1[x_, y_, z_] = (g1[x, y, z] + g2[x, y, z])/(Sqrt[2] Sqrt[1 + a2]);
chi2[x_, y_, z_] = (g1[x, y, z] - g2[x, y, z])/(Sqrt[2] Sqrt[1 - a2]);
fun[x_, y_, z_] := {chi1[x, y, z], chi2[x, y, z]};

J[p_, q_, r_, s_] := fun[x1, y1, z1][[p]]*fun[x2, y2, z2][[q]]*fun[x1, y1, z1][[s]]*
                     fun[x2, y2, z2][[r]]*1/Sqrt[(x1 - x2)^2 + (y1 - y2)^2 + (z1 - z2)^2] // FullSimplify

A1 = Assuming[a1 > 0, 
     Integrate[J[2, 2, 1, 1] /. {x2 -> x1 + dx, y2 -> y1 + dy, z2 -> z1 + dz}, 
     {x1, -Inf, Inf}, {y1, -Inf, Inf}, 
     {z1, -Inf, Inf}]];

A2 = Assuming[r > 0, A1 /. {dx -> r Sin[\[Theta]] Cos[\[CurlyPhi]], 
     dy -> r Sin[\[Theta]] Sin[\[CurlyPhi]], dz -> r Cos[\[Theta]]} // FullSimplify];

A3 = Assuming[a1 > 0 && d > 0, Integrate[A2 r^2 Sin[\[Theta]], {r, 0, Inf}, 
     {\[Theta], 0, \[Pi]}, {\[CurlyPhi], 0, 2 \[Pi]}]];

A3 /. {d -> 1.401, a1 -> 0.416613, a2 -> g1g2}
```

Comment: At the end of your calculations you substitute some variables with their numerical values. Have you tried doing that as early as possible in your calculations instead? That will probably greatly simplify your integrands and the subsequent calculations.

Comment: Are you computing electron repulsion integrals?

Comment: Yes I’m calculating some electron repulsion integrals